# Xamarin forms PushAsync opens a blank page

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigation

I'm currently working on a project where I received push notification on the device, and when taping the notification it should open a specific page.

I tried it on an Android 5.1, but when I tap the notification, it first opens the page and immediately after that it opens a blank page, whithout any navigation bar and I don't understand why...

Here is my code:

When I receive the the message on android I perform the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
intent.PutExtra("key", "message");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

Notification notif = new Notification.Builder(this)
                        .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)
                        .SetContentTitle("Alert")
                        .SetContentText("alert message")
                        .SetAutoCancel(true)
                        .SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Sound | NotificationDefaults.Vibrate)
                        .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .SetPriority((int)NotificationPriority.High)
                        .Build();

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
notificationManager.Notify(0, notif);
```

When taped it opens the MainActivity which does the following:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
    ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
    if (app == null)
       app = new App();
    LoadApplication(app);

    // If the user tapped a notification
    if (Intent.Extras != null)
    {
        Data data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(Intent.Extras.GetString("key"));
        MessagingCenter.Send<Data>(data, "Show data");
    }
}
```

Finally I have a DataPage (sets as the MainPage of the App, inside a NavigationPage) which does this:

```
public DataPage()
{
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Data>(this, "Show data", (sender) =>
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new DataDetail(sender));
    });
}
```

I don't really understand why this does not work properly...
Especially since if I do

```
await Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new DataPage(data)));
```

And create a second constructor in the DataPage:

```
DataPage(Data data)
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new DataDetail(data));
}
```

It works fine. (But I don't like this, it looks very... not nice)

Answer (score 0):

I can barely understand the connections between your `Data`, your `DataDetail`, your `DataPage` and your `MainPage`.

By my side, I think `Data` is like a data model based on your code `Data data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(Intent.Extras.GetString("key"));`, but inside this class you code `await Navigation.PushAsync(new DataDetail(data));`, where does this `Navigation` come from?

Never mind, I guess that you have a `MainPage` wrapped by `NavigationPage`, and you want to navigate it to your `DataPage` when you click the notification. If so, then there is no problem with your `Notification` part.

To show the data in your `DetailPage`, you can create a constructor with parameter for example:

```cs
public partial class DataPage : ContentPage
{
    public DataPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public DataPage(int count)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //set the data to the UI
        label.Text = "This is Count: " + count;
    }
}
```

You can create a single instance for `Navigation` in `MainPage`, so can it be used in `Data` class:

```cs
public static INavigation Navi;

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Navi = this.Navigation;
}
```

Then my `Data` class is as simple as following:

```cs
public class Data
{
    public Data()
    {
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Data>(this, "show data", (sender) =>
        {
            MainPage.Navi.PushAsync(new DataPage(this.Count));
        });
    }

    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Finally in `MainActivity`:

```cs
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
    ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
    LoadApplication(new App());

    if (Intent.Extras != null)
    {
        int count = Intent.Extras.GetInt("count", -1);
        var data = new Data() { Count = count };
        MessagingCenter.Send<Data>(data, "show data");
    }
}
```

You can modify the `Data` class as you need. The following is the rendering image of my demo:

[image]

**Update:**

Based on our discussion, your message is directly sent to `DataPage`, then in `App` class in PCL, wrap this `DataPage` with `NavigationPage`: `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new DataPage());`.

In the `MainAcitvity` send message like this:

```
if (Intent.Extras != null)
{
    int count = Intent.Extras.GetInt("count", -1);
    var data = new Data() { Count = count }; //fake data, change it to your data

    var navipage = App.Current.MainPage as NavigationPage;
    var datapage = navipage.CurrentPage as DataPage;
    MessagingCenter.Send<DataPage, Data>(datapage, "show data", data);
}
```

And in the `DataPage`:

```
public DataPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<DataPage, Data>(this, "show data", (sender, arg) =>
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new DataDetail(arg));
    });
}
```

Of course we need to create an instructor in `DataDetail` with parameter:

```
public DataDetail(Data data)
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry I made a typo... The class that subscribe to the message "show data" of the messaging center is the DataPage, which is the MainPage of the project.
I made a typo in the constructor, it should be

    public DataPage()
    {
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe(...);
    }

And since my DataPage IS the MainPage, wrapped in a NavigationPage like this

    public App()
    {
        ...
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new DataPage);
        ....
    }

It seems to be as you show there, but yet it does'nt work properly

Comment: So to be clear: My MainPage is the DataPage, which is wrapped in a NavigationPage and shows a ListView bound to a list of data (but it seems irrelevant to the problem). Then the DataDetail is a page that show in detail a specific data, which is as you said a model class.

Therefore, the await Navigation in DataPage() seems legit to me.

Comment: @Simon, yes, but your messagecenter sent message to `Data` class, in that class, there should have no `Navigation` property. That's why I used a single instance of `Navigation` in `MainPage`. So your requirement is to get the data from notification and show it in your `DataPage`, and your data page is the root page of `NavigationPage`, am I right? The `DataDetail` is irrelevant here?

Comment: Not exactly. The DataPage is indeed the rootpage of the Navigation. When I tap the notification and send message through the MessagingCenter, it is the DataPage that receives it (I checked it with the debugger, and the message is effectively received). Upon the reception of the message DataPage, I want my DataPage to open a new DataDetail page, showing the details of the data.So it is the DataDetail that I want to open that is not showing properly.

Comment: @Simon, OK, last question, what is the `Data` here in your code `MessagingCenter.Send<Data>(data, "Show data");`? It should be a class right? I saw you sent data to `Data` and subscribe the message in the constructor of `Data`. The sender here is also data with type `Data`.

Comment: This is where my typo was, but I corrected it. Data is a model class, it only contains public properties.
I send a the Data to my DataPage, and it is in the DataPage constructor that I subscribe to the message (sorry to have confused you with this typo)

Comment: @Simon, I updated my answer, hope this time it meets your requirement. If this answer helps, could you please mark this answer?

Comment: I tried your solution but unfortunatly I still have the same problem.. Once again the DataDetail page is open and a fraction of a second later a blank page opens on top of it...

Comment: @Simon, strange, works fine by my side, maybe you can share your project.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally solved the problem. 
It seems that it was caused by the fact that I made a static App variable in the MainActivity in order to create it only once.

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    static App app;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        ...
        if(app == null)
            app = new App();
        ...
     }
}
```

I did that because otherwise the Current.Properties of the app instance was reset.

Now I changed that and I no longer have this problem:
I call the Current.SavePropertiesAsync() to save the Current.Properties and therefore I can remove the static instance of App in the MainActivity. It solved the blank page problem.

But this made another problem. When I tapped the notification, it works correctly the first time, but after that it opened the requested page multiple times (The second notification tapped opened 2 pages, the third opened 3, ...). I don't understand why it did that, but it seemed to be caused by the MessagingCenter. So I remove the MessagingCenter part and simply did this in the MainActivity:

```
if (Intent.Extras != null)
{
     Data data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(Intent.Extras.GetString("key"));
     DataPage currentPage = (DataPage)((NavigationPage)App.Current.MainPage).CurrentPage;
     currentPage.OpenDataDetails(data);
}
```

And in the DataPage I have this function

```
public async void OpenDataDetails(Data data)
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new DataDetail(data));
}
```

This does work as expected, so now I'm happy.

But still, I don't understand why when I had a static App instance in MainActivity it opened a blank page, nor why it opened multiple pages with the MessagingCenter...